# How to redirect http to https url in nginx?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

we have many domain on our server but we want to redirect some domain http to https permanently .
like our domain

```
http://example.com/         //main public folder
http://example.com/member   //member folder
http://example.com/online   //online folder folder
```

please tell me what specific rules for these domain only

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

That will force https on everything. If you want to do it for specific folders, use this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/folder/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: can you say how nginx will use .htaccess configuration?